Basement subfloor - DMX + XPS (DuroSpan), no OSB?
Looking to put down LVP.  Home built in 1980, located in Quebec, has a sump pump.
Having watched RenoVision subfloor video, and learned of the DIY DriCore+ of DuroSpan + OSB, but this doesn't have a airgap for moisture. Do I need OSB if I am just putting down LVP. Is it feasible to do DMX 1 Step + DuroSpan to create a air gap for moisture as well provide an R value and then do LVP on top?  Will I regret it from a walking on feel perspective?
If this is a feasible direction, should the DuroSpan be tapcon into the foundation like is done with OSB so there is no float/bounce?
